# Is it possible to wrap two similar class functions into one class in C#?

Tags: c#

I am working with SqlConnection and AdomdConnection objects in C#.

SqlConnection is constructed from: DbConnection, ICloneable.

AdomdConnection is constructed from: Component, IDbConnection, IDisposable, ICloneable.

I hoped I could use a common interface or class type to pass around but that doesn't seem to be an option because they don't share a common type, that I can tell.

They both have similar methods that I need to call but as I am going to write some logic around calling them for either I wanted to wrap them into their own class and then just call that class and let it worry about the underlying type.

Initially, I thought I could use something like this:

```
public class ConnectionWrapper {
  protected object _Conn;

  public ConnectionWrapper(object Conn) {
   _Conn = Conn;
  }

  public void Open() {
   if (_Conn is SqlConnection) {
    ((SqlConnection) _Conn).Open();
   } else if (_Conn is AdomdConnection) {
    ((AdomdConnection) _Conn).Open();
   }
  }
 }
```

But I can't help but wonder that there isn't a better way to do it.

I came across the TypeMap class (see question 298976) which would be a more readable way to do it, but I couldn't figure out how to use return values with that, but still wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Looks like something you could solve with generics.

Comment: But you don't need to as both Connection Classes already implement the same Interfaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`IDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx) - that is common to both types.

`SqlConnection` inherits from `DbConnection` which in turn implements the `IDbConnection` interface.  This interface is also implemented by `AdomdConnection`.

Therefore you can use the `IDbConnection` interface to represent both types

Comment: Just to flesh this correct answer out for the OP, SqlConnection inherits from and abstract class DBConnection which implements IDbConnection.

Comment: Thanks to all for answers - Just out of interest, if there wasn't a common interface that could passed but there were common methods how could that be wrapped?

Comment: You would wrap it much in the same way you showed in your question.

Answer (score 2):

> SqlConnection is constructed from: DbConnection, ICloneable.

Yes, it is, but `DBConnection` itself extends and implements `Component, IDbConnection, IDisposable`

So you could handle both objects as `IDbConnection`